# Is it possible to get a list of Windows 8 notifications

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Whether through the UI, or code (preferably) both. Can you see a list, or get the history of windows 8 notifications?

Also it would be nice to do it from a metro App, but even in general from a desktop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible without some how digging into deep internal state of the notification service etc.

Comment: Which would be completely unsupported and may stop working at any time. Make sure your customers understand this.

Comment: thanks. also also validated by raymond. I just had really thought and hoped there would be something more than just happening to be there when it comes up on the screen for a few seconds.

Comment: The [notification guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465391.aspx) specifically say that notifications should be designed so that users can miss them without negative conseqences.